# How to make a listview accept and display as much data as entered

Tags: android

If anyone knows, I was learning from O'reily Head First Android development book and got stuck in the code of page of 338 where it uses `addTimeRecord` but it doesn't work acually... In the example or following code as I press "Save the data" `time` and `note` fields should be added to listview. Can somebody help please?

**First the MainActivity**

```
package com.sigdel.practicelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter;
ListView listView;
TimeRecord record;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //until now listview is displayed but is empty so now we add data in list
    //and control its behaviour by adapter
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.times_list);
    TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter =new TimeTrackerAdapter();
    //listView is the name for the listview and timeTrackerAdapter is the name for adapter
    listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.time_list_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.add_time_menu_item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTimeActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent,TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String time = data.getStringExtra("time");
            String note = data.getStringExtra("note");
            Toast.makeText(this, time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, note,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            timeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord( new TimeRecord(time, notes));
            //this above line doesn't work addTimeRecord is not defined 
            timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

}
```

**TimeRecord**

```
package com.sigdel.practicelistview;
//creating data object called TimeRecord
//Based on the app design, you’ll need to store a
//time and note for each time entered. Rather than
//separately storing that information, create a data
//object to store both fields in a single object.
//you build an Adapters that stores
//data, build your own data object to keep
//your data organized

public class TimeRecord {
    private String time;
    private String notes;

    public TimeRecord(String time, String notes) {
        //TimeRecord is the object here. this refers to TimeRecord. now you define your object            constructor
        // you say that your TimeRecord object should have time and notes as fields
        // that have time and notes as variables
        // thus time and notes are ready to accept the returned values to define the
        //TimeRecord object
        this.time = time;
        this.notes = notes;
        //ghokne
    }

    //Now get ready to return time and notes values to create the object to be displayed
    //in the listview
    //Below are the methods to return the values to define object
    public String getTime() { return time; }
    //Ok once real time is returned, now you need to set it
    public void setTime(String time) { this.time = time; }
    public String getNotes() { return notes; }
    public void setNotes(String notes) { this.notes = notes; }
}
```

**TimeTrackerAdapter**

```
package com.sigdel.practicelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<TimeRecord> times = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return times.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return getItem(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        //The first time getView is called on your Adapter,
        //the View passed in is null. Since the Adapter
        //knows how the data should be displayed, it’s up to
        //the Adapter to instantiate the View the first time.
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        //The TimeRecord object in the ArrayList at the index has everything you need to populate the     view.
        //say that time holds the object in a row of the index
        TimeRecord time = times.get(index);
        //say that the time_view of the layout should display the value carried by timeTextView
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        //set the string in getTime() part of TimeRecord object as timeTextView.
        //i.e timeTextView is the layout, time is the object and getTime() is the time part of the object
        timeTextView.setText(time.getTime());
        TextView notesTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
        //set the string in getNotes() part of TimeRecord object as notesTextView.
        //notesTextView layout ma time object ko getNOtes() part ko string lai set garne
        notesTextView.setText(time.getNotes());
        return view;
    }

    public TimeTrackerAdapter() {
        times.add(new TimeRecord("38:23", "Feeling good!"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("48:23", "Feelingjj good!"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("18:23", "Feelingookkl good!"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("32:23", "Feelioong good!"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: How does't work? Throws `NullPointerException` or just does nothing?
Also the code for `TimeTrackerAdapter` class would be handy. Could you post it or a link to it?

Comment: @EugenPechanec The only thing that wasted my 6 hrs is this line of code  timeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord( new TimeRecord(time, notes)); line ..I don't understand from where does addTimeRecord come from??

Comment: It's a method from class `TimeTrackerAdapter` (in another file). It has to be in the book too. And if you managed to compile and run it is surely in the project as well.

Comment: @EugenPechanec this listView has its items in TimeTrackerAdapter as you can see in the code. In TimeTrackerAdapter an object has been defined TimeRecord(String, String) and data is entered by changing the string values in the object in TimeTrackerAdapter. Now i receive two strings 'time' and 'note' from intent in MainActivity when a save button was clicked. And i want these strings to be added in the list as TimeRecord(time,note) object. so how can i add the data TimeRecord(time,note) in TimeTrackerAdapter class from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. You'll get stack overflow on TimeTrackerAdapter.getItem(int index).

The method is infinitely calling itself. You might want to return something like this:

```
@Override
public TimeRecord getItem(int index) {
    return times.get(i);
}
```

### 2. Implement TimeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord(TimeRecord)

Your adapter lacks method for adding new items. You could implement it in this way:

```
public void add(TimeRecord record) {
    items.add(record);
}
```

Now after you call `timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the data should be displayed in the list.